# Error converting class component to function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I'm trying to convert a class component to functional component.

Class component: [classBasedComponent.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-1vkuc?file=/src/classBasedComponents.js) [Original code included in this file]

Progress made by me:

Function Component: [functionComponent.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-1vkuc?file=/src/functionComponent.js) [My progress]

Here is the GitHub link for reference: https://github.com/codebushi/gatsby-starter-dimension

Here are my errors:

- 12:19  warning  'setArticle' is assigned a value but never used
  no-unused-vars
- 27:11  error    'timeoutId' is not defined no-undef
- 33:6   warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:
  'handleClickOutside'. Either include it or remove the dependency
  array        react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
- 45:30  error    'setWrapperRef' is not defined no-undef
- 58:37  warning  Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
- 66:23  error    Unexpected use of 'location' no-restricted-globals
- 80:28  error    'setWrapperRef' is not defined no-undef

I'm still getting errors with it. Where can I improvise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Let's focus on the errors.

> 27:11 error 'timeoutId' is not defined no-undef

You declared this variable as `timeoutId` but switch between `timeoutId` and `timeOutId` when referring to it. In your current sandbox it is `timeoutId`, so all the `timeOutId` usages are flagged as undeclared. Settle on one or the other and be consistent.

> 45:30 error 'setWrapperRef' is not defined no-undef

and

> 80:28 error 'setWrapperRef' is not defined no-undef

This looks to be a function called by `Main` to pass back out a ref to *something* that is then referenced in `handleClickOutside`. Use a react ref to store the value.

```
const wrapperRef = React.useRef(null); // create ref to store value

...

const setWrapperRef = node => wrapperRef.current = node; // set current ref value

...

const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
  if (!wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) { // access current ref value
    if (isArticleVisible) {
      handleCloseArticle();
    }
  }
}

...

<Main
  isArticleVisible={isArticleVisible}
  timeout={timeout}
  articleTimeout={articleTimeout}
  article={article}
  onCloseArticle={handleCloseArticle}
  setWrapperRef={setWrapperRef} // attach ref value updater
/>
```

> 66:23 error Unexpected use of 'location' no-restricted-globals

`location` was previously received via `props`, it's likely still received via `props`.

```
<Layout location={props.location}>
```

Or since I see no other references to `props` in your functional component, just destructure it in the component signature. If you need to access more prop values you can simply also destructure them here.

```
function IndexPage({ location }) { ...
```

## And now the warnings

> 12:19 warning 'setArticle' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

This just means it was defined and never used, but upon inspection of the class-based component, updating the `article` value occurs in `handleOpenArticle` and `handleCloseArticle`. So let's do the same in your functional component.

The issue here was that you were passing extra arguments to the `setIsArticleVisible` updater that get ignored. `useState` updaters don't shallowly merge updates and yours are declared to hold only a single value. I suggest to also use a functional state update to toggle the boolean state values.

```
handleOpenArticle(article) {
  this.setState({
    isArticleVisible: !this.state.isArticleVisible,
    article
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      timeout: !this.state.timeout
    });
  }, 325);

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      articleTimeout: !this.state.articleTimeout
    });
  }, 350);
}

handleCloseArticle() {
  this.setState({
    articleTimeout: !this.state.articleTimeout
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      timeout: !this.state.timeout
    });
  }, 325);

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      isArticleVisible: !this.state.isArticleVisible,
      article: ""
    });
  }, 350);
}
```

becomes

```
const handleOpenArticle = (article) => {
  setIsArticleVisible(isArticleVisible => !isArticleVisible);
  setArticle(article);
  setTimeout(() => setTimeout(timeout => !timeout), 325);
  setTimeout(() => setArticleTimeout(articleTimeout => !articleTimeout), 350);
};

const handleCloseArticle = (article) => {
  setArticleTimeout(articleTimeout => !articleTimeout);
  setTimeout(() => setTimeout(timeout => !timeout), 325);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsArticleVisible(isArticleVisible => !isArticleVisible);
    setArticle("");
  }, 350);
};
```

> 33:6 warning React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:
> 'handleClickOutside'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Normally you would want to include all the dependencies for the effect so all values are correct, but here it is clear the intention is to add the listeners when the component mounts, and remove them when unmounting. You can add an `eslint-disable` comment for *just* that line. I suggest also moving the `timeoutId`/`timeOutId` declaration inside the effect since it isn't used outside it. It's also safe to pass `undefined` to `clearTimeout`, it can handle it, so remove the conditional check.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading("");
  }, 100);

  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
  };
  // Effect triggered on component mount only
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

> 58:37 warning Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq

Not sure where this logic came from, but it's replaced by the `wrapperRef` error fix above.

## Note:

*All the above suggestions are based **entirely** on your self-described/reported issues and what I could see flagged in your sandbox. There could be other potential issues popping up after these are addressed (possibly because they were masked by them.*

Comment: I'm getting a follow-up error:
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This error seems to be caused by useEffect.

Comment: I'm using article as a prop. I'm using a button with code :
 <button onClick={props.onOpenArticle('id')}>Work</button>
in another file. This is causing infinite loops.

Comment: @KillMe Does this new error have a stacktrace? Can you tell what component is causing the error? In the `IndexPage` component in your codesandbox the `useEffect` isn't unconditionally setting state and has no dependencies so it won't be retriggered on subsequent renders.

Comment: @KillMe Ah, can you share that other file and error details in your question then?

Comment: Here is the file: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-1vkuc?file=/src/header.js

Comment: Line in header.js : <button onClick={props.onOpenArticle("intro")}>Intro</button>

Comment: @KillMe Guess we would need to see what is rendering your `Header` component and passing it an `onOpenArticle` callback to call. I'm guessing that it updates some state somewhere. `Header` itself doesn't have any state to update-render-loop on.

Comment: I have added some more code:https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-1vkuc?file=/src/main.js

Comment: Should I use useMemo or useCallback in case of re-renders?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226688/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-killme).

Comment: @KillMe It's a typo, you are invoking the callback immediately. It should be something like `<button onClick={() => props.onOpenArticle("intro")}>Intro</button>`.